# Installing pip is not working in python < 3.6

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use these steps with bitbucket CI to deploy an application:

```
 script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y python-dev
    - curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
    - python get-pip.py
    ... and a few more steps
```

However, the `python get-pip.py` step fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 24226, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 199, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "/tmp/tmpUgc5ng/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why isn't it working now? Does it depend on the operating system?

---

<sub>For the equivalent issue with **upgrading** `pip` in old Python installations, see [Upgrading pip fails with syntax error caused by sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896334).</sub>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65866417/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65865755/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20SyntaxError

Comment: @phd Thanks. I'd be glad to accept the answer if you post it. :)

Comment: To make it a better answer I need to know what Python version do you use? 2.7?

Comment: @phd Its just used in bitbucket CI not sure about the version. so i presume its 2.7

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`pip` 21.0 [dropped support for Python 2 and 3.5](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id1). The later versions require Python 3.6+. The syntax `f""` is supported by [Python 3.6+](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

To install `pip` for Python 2.7 install it from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/ :

```
- curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
- python get-pip.py
- python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0"
```

The last command is to upgrade to the latest **supported** version.

- For Python 2.7 the latest supported is currently `pip` 20.3.4.
- For Python 3.6 install from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/
- For Python 3.5 install from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/
- For Python 3.4 install from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.4/
- For Python 3.4 the upgrade command is

  ```
  python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 19.2"
  ```

Comment: The upgrade command is not needed, as get-pip.py will install the latest supported version

Comment: @ColinPickard I prefer to be: a) explicit; b) to write down a command for future reference if a user would ever want to try to upgrade `pip` once again.

Comment: This is fine. But what is the command for 3.5. After downloading from the link?

Comment: @Shivani The same as in the post: `python get-pip.py`

Comment: This does not work for me - pip stays in version 8.1.1 instead of the installed: ```Successfully installed pip-20.3.4```

Comment: @RoyLevy Fina all `pip` scripts in the `$PATH` (`type -a pip`) and remove excessive/old ones.

Comment: Worked for me on `Ubuntu Server 16.04.7` with `python2.7` and `python3.5`. Thanks!

Comment: ERROR: This script does not work on Python 2.7 The minimum supported Python version is 3.7. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Did you read the answer? The URL is clearly in the middle.

Comment: @phd and you? this is not work!!!

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Works perfectly: `python2.7 get-pip.py` ->
**Successfully installed pip-20.3.4** No problem at all.

Comment: @phd ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0
/var/tmp/tmpPpfPBt/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor That's a different error, not what you said before.

Comment: it is same error just full output does not fit here

Answer (score 11):

I solved it by firstly run

`python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 19.2"`

and then

`python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0"`.

It seems reinstall my pip 20.3.4 and the error disappreared!

Comment: This is quite strange but, yeah it fixed my problem too.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. pip is wonky as hell.

Comment: You're a life saver. Installing pip is apparently rocket science, but this works.

Answer (score 2):

> ***This worked for me:On Mac:***

Install `pyenv` as well as upgrade your python following the instructions on this [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/)

Then in your terminal, if you run `python -V` and you still get the old version(system predefined version) showing:

To resolve this:

In your terminal run: `alias python=python3`

Then in your terminal execute  `python` and you should now see that your system is using the python version you installed-:That is if you followed and completed the steps [Here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) Correctly.

[image: python switched]

Restart your terminal(close/reopen):

Now you can finally install pip:

```
Read more about pip instalation steps [here][3]
```

1:In your terminal execute :`$ python -m ensurepip --upgrade`

2: Download the script, from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py.

> `But..**NB**: instead of navigating to the exact link provided,check out the available versions of pip here:` [pipversions](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/)

Select the latest version:

[image: pipversions page]

Then select getpip.py link to get the file and save it into your directory on your machine:

[image: get-pip]
cd into the folder where you saved the newly downloaded script and execute:

Then execute:

```
python get-pip.py
```

[image: pippy folder]

Pip installed successfully:

[image: successfully installed]

Answer (score 1):

For me python 3.5 on aws ec2 below worked
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py

Then
sudo python3.5 get-pip.py[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4N0G.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried all thing but my solution was download old get-pip version and install.

1. download: `curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py` the file `get-pip.py`
2. install: `python get-pip.py` or `python2 get-pip.py`
3. enjoy

This is worked on Debian systems.

---

Edit: A better solution is always to install a Python version that is long supported. If at all you need to work with an older version - only then must one resort to the above workaround.

Comment: /urllib3/util/ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

Answer (score -1):

1. Uninstall existing pip on your machine
2. Run this cmd in ubuntu or any linux machine

   ```
   curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
   python3 get-pip.py
   ```

It will work

Comment: As it's currently written, your answer is unclear.  Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked and to explain how this answer is different from others already posted. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This seems to be a restatement of previous answers anyway.