# Why do I get invalid syntax error when I try to do anything with pip?

Tags: python, pip

I run latest python 3.9.1 and the pip doesn't work, I tried to install, uninstall and it still gives me the same error (below). I am not sure what's wrong as I tried everything I found on the net, it gives me the **invalid syntax** error (please see below).

Any ideas on what should I do?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If it doesn't know what f-strings are, as seems to be the problem according to your error message, then you're not running Python 3.9.1, as you think you are, but some version older than 3.6.

Comment: How do you try to run pip? Have you tried `python3.9 -m pip [command]`?

Comment: apoligies I accidentally pasted another error code from another post I was reading! I changed the post can you have a look again! I tried running uninstall commands and reinstall but every-time I try it gives me this error

Comment: How did you even *install* `pip`? Somehow, you installed it as part of your Python 2.7 installation, which absolutely does not support f-strings.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/1365018)

Comment: I installed it when I was on python 2.7 but then I updated it to 3.9.1 but the pip is sort of working but I cant uninstall it for instance! Wonder why