# Error using pip install on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros

I was trying to install a python module for both python3 and python2, and I had to upgrade pip, however, after running

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

it would give me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure what the issue is, and whenever I use the command to install anything else, it's the same issue

Edit: I also tried to use pip3 and ran into the same error

Comment: pip dropped support for py3.5- and py2. also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869296/installing-pip-is-not-working-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think that f-strings syntax is only available python3 and onwards, maybe trying `pip3 install --upgrade [pip|pip3]`

Comment: I am getting the same error, should I uninstall then reinstall?

Comment: some OS include python (pip) for misc tasks. Don't uninstall simply install python3 along with pip3... same error with `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` ?