# How to get rid of "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error when typing pip --version or pip3 --version?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use `pip` or `pip3` `--version` option but both of them give me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error.

```
masoud@masoud-ThinkPad-E550:~$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/masoud/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/masoud/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And:

```
masoud@masoud-ThinkPad-E550:~$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/masoud/.local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/masoud/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix this? I have seen some fixes by removing some files but I am not sure which directory I need to remove.

Comment: Related: [Installing pip is not working in python < 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65869296/3890632)

Comment: According to the status on https://pypi.org/project/pip/ the current version of `pip` doesn't support Python 3.5 anymore.

Comment: @Matthias OK, thanks!