# pip install prettytable and got error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python-2.7, pip, prettytable

MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3, python 2.7.

I run `sudo easy_install pip` to install pip, then run `pip install prettytable`, finally I got errors below, anyone can help~

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: prettytable supports Python 3.6+

You can see that on their pypi page and from the syntax they are using

Comment: is there any way to install an old version prettytable for python 2.7?

Comment: Why are you still using python 2.7? It's reached EOL.

Comment: There isn't a way to install it because its source code is written for 3.6+. If you aren't forced to use 2.7 I suggest you move to 3.7 or 3.8 because they have been around for some time and most packages will have support for them.

Comment: thx for you answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758 to fix your `pip`.

`prettytable` 1.0.1 supports Python 2.7. Install it with

```
pip install prettytable==1.0.1
```

or

```
pip install "prettytable<2.0"
```