# Pip command line "ImportError: No Module Named Typing"

Tags: python, pip

Running the following command gives me the following error:

```
pip install pygame
```

**Error Stack:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 171, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named 'typing'
```

Comment: Python 3.4 was released over 7 years ago and has already reached end-of-life. Current versions of `pip` might not support Python 3.4 anymore.

Comment: On what version of Windows? What Python "distribution"? [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution))? What version?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It looks like you are importing from the package 'typing' but you do not have it installed. Try installing the package:

```
pip install typing
```

Comment: A much better fix is to upgrade to a recent Python version which has it included in the standard library. Chances are the library you are trying to use won't work very well in 3.4 either.

Comment: in the question pip itself is failing as it tries to import typing and typing is not installed. so you cannot run pip install to fix this. e.g. redhat run `yum install python-typing` However, the real problem might be that python packages are upgraded to python3.? and pip is running python2 so ... heh, ...

Comment: @gaoithe I had the same issue for my python2 pip. Turns out that I needed to downgrade pip. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/5195136

Answer (score 35):

Running this line in a Mac terminal fixed it for me:

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I had the same issue. I also first tried the `pip3 install pygame` which was previously mentioned, before running this line. You may have to do that first. For the individual who said to try

```
pip install typing
```

that line of code will simply produce the same error. To fix it, you have to use to the aforementioned command(s).

Comment: been having this issue for few days pip complaining the same error for everything.  `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip` worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

I also ran into the same problem, because I made the foolish mistake of upgrading pip as suggested by Python.

I fixed this by downloading `get_pip.py` for python3.4 at https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.4/get-pip.py and running it:

```
python get_pip.py
```

It will automatically download the latest compatible version of pip (19.1.1 in this case).

Comment: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
download and then `python get_pip.py`

Answer (score 9):

Try to:

1. `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py`
2. `python get-pip.py`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: that helped me, but with python3.6 instead of 2.7

Answer (score 8):

Do the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If there is a problem, do:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If there is still a problem, remove and recreate your venv. And Reinstall your requirements:

```
rm -rf venv
python3.9 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: `File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py"` means he is using Windows

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error on Ubuntu 20.04 when using `python3.9`, I tried to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

The output advised me to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, which had solved my problem and `python3.9` is running fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have also met this problem. Any command that starts with `pip` have the same error, `ImportError: No module named 'typing'`.

**Finally, `python -m pip install typing` solved it.**

Answer (score 0):

I had this error using pip because my [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) installation with Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 were crossed using the versions and pip.

My solution was to uninstall Python 2.7 and pip 2.7. I also uninstalled Python 3.5 and pip 3.

I then installed Python 3.7 using these directions: *[Installing the latest Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04](https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-the-latest-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/)*

I'm not sure if uninstalling 3.5 and adding 3.7 is necessary. You may just be able to remove 2.7 and be good, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall, you can specify the version of `pip` that corresponds to the Python version that you want to use, for example `python3.7 -m pip install some_package`

Answer (score -3):

Try this one:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Comment: Why does 'pip3' vs. 'pip' make a difference?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This is because, in operating systems Mac or Linux, They have Python 2.7 built-in (i think, for the most part) So, if you run ```pip``` The command line is gonna run Python 2.7 pip interpreter. When you do ```pip3``` It tells the command line to run the Python 3.9 pip interpreter.