# $pip command gets ImportError: No module named typing

Tags: python, pip

When I am trying to run the following command:

`$ pip`

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/ssm-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named typing
```

Does anyone knows how to solve the issue? Thanks!

Here are my python versions:

```
$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.12
$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) is part of the standard library, so it doesn't need to be installed. However, it wasn't added until Python 3.5, so it may not be available in all versions.

Comment: What's the result of ```$ pip --version``` ?

Comment: A duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67278017/pip-command-line-importerror-no-module-named-typing. try `pip install typing`

Comment: You need to downgrade `pip` for all your Pythons. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758 . Your problem is different but the process of downgrading and URLs are the same.

Comment: Thank you @phd for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869296/installing-pip-is-not-working-in-python-3-6/65871131#65871131). I followed the solution and downgraded pip and that solves the issue.