# Traceback error is returned when trying to run "pip" command

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

When I am trying to run pip I run into an error which goes as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in 
    load_entry_point('pip==21.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named typing
```

I have tried to force reinstall pip but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue. pip3 seems to be working fine.

Tried to do "pip3 install typing" but that didn't work out for me.

Comment: Did you use `pip install typing` to install the package for `typing`?

Comment: I did, that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ImportError%3A+No+module+named+typing

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install typing
```

Try this command.

Comment: yep, did try that. The problem still persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67278017/pip-command-line-importerror-no-module-named-typing try answers in this question