# Can not install pyperclip on mac, error ImportError: No module named typing

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to install pyperclip for the python course "automate the boring stuff with python" on my Mac.

When I type `pip install pyperclip` to console I get the error :

```
ImportError: No module named typing.
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip install typing` should solve your problem.
You can also downgrade your `pip` version.
`python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < VERSION_NUM"`

[Typing Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67278017/pip-command-line-importerror-no-module-named-typing)
[pip solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869296/installing-pip-is-not-working-in-python-3-6/65871131#65871131)

Comment: brings back: line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named typing

Comment: brings back : ImportError: No module named typing

Comment: So what you did differently that it didn't work at first and now it does?