# "ImportError: No Module Named Typing"-tried a lot of stuff already

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to download opencv but I am getting an error that is this:

> ImportError: No module named typing

I already tried everyone solution on this answer and nothing worked:

[Pip command line "ImportError: No Module Named Typing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67278017/pip-command-line-importerror-no-module-named-typing)

Comment: What version of Python?  `typing` was added in 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

try importing the whole OpenCV package
for windows use:
`pip install openCV-python`
or for Mac use: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/db2/tutorial_macos_install.html