# ImportError: No module named typing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, python-typing

I'm trying to create a [python2 virtualenv](https://gist.github.com/simonw/4835a22c79a8d3c29dd155c716b19e16), so I try `pip install virtualenv` and get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named typing
```

I get an almost identical error with `pip install typing`

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named typing
```

A lot of solutions suggest using python3 but I'm specifically trying to create a python 2 virtual environment

---

I'm running MacOS Big Sur on a 2018 Intel i3 Mac Mini

Comment: I don't know who downvoted all 3 answers, but it most likely would deter people from leaving more answers  if they saw all answers downvoted

Comment: All answers at that point focused on the wrong thing, not solving your problem.

Comment: You need to downgrade pip for your Python. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758/ . Your problem is different but the process of downgrading and URLs are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2 reached its end of life (EOL). Consequently the support for Python 2 was removed from `pip` in version 21. You need to downgrade `pip` to version 20.

---

I tried this (in shell command line):

```
# downgrade pip to 20.3.4
pip install --user pip==20.3.4
# better: 'pip<21', but it must be quoted!

# install virtualenv if not installed already
pip install --user virtualenv

# create a new venv for old python
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 /tmp/venv27

# update pip back to the recent version
pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

Now, `pip --version` shows version 21, but inside the activated environment there is version 20:

```
sh-5.0$ pip --version
pip 21.1.1 from /home/vpfb/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

sh-5.0$ pwd
/tmp/venv27/bin

sh-5.0$ source ./activate

(venv27) sh-5.0$ pip --version
pip 20.3.4 from /tmp/venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

I tried to install a random package in the venv and it succeeded.

Comment: How would you suggest doing this

Comment: with `pip==20.3.4` (latest pip 20.X.Y) argument as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip

Comment: Is there a way to do this all in a virtual environment?

Comment: When I try `pip install pip==20.3.4` I get the same error about typing

Comment: @Sam Since your pip is already “corrupted”, you can’t use it to install another version of it. You’ll need to install it from scratch some other way. Consult the documentation for the most appropriate method for your system.

Comment: So after removing pip inside `/usr/local/bin/pip` I ran `sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4` after this I was able to install `virtualenv`.  When I tried using `pip install --user pip==20.3.4` , I got the same no module named typing error. Could you include this information in your answer?

Comment: @Sam I guess you might have multiple pips installed. Use the full path e.g. `/usr/local/bin/pip` and verify with `--version` before installing that you run the version you want.

Comment: I think i just have pip and pip3, I got this computer a few weeks ago

Comment: @Sam maybe there are also other issues. Please update your question with more details to make it reproducible step by step: which commands did you run (with version info) to setup your environment and which command failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to use another version. I know you've been hearing this a lot, but python 2.7 isn't supported anymore (since 1st January 2021) so thats why it might be showing an error.

Comment: What exactly does not supported mean? What I'm trying to do is run an [old Github project](https://github.com/ksallberg/wallstreet_tycoon) without changing anything. Python2 may not be supported, but is this still possible?

Comment: I dont think it will work anymore. Not supported means it simply does not work anymore.

Comment: @shreyas That’s not what it means at all. The existing software will keep working fine as it always has. There’s no kill switch in it. It just means that no further updates will be released ever, and don’t-come-crying-to-us-if-something-doesn’t-work.

Answer (score 0):

typing module is only valid for python version 3.5 and above.

https://pypi.org/project/typing/

Answer (score 0):

[`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) is

> New in version 3.5.

So it should  be no surprise that `import typing` caused failure in `python2.7`. So if you find project using `import typing` is either for python at least 3.5 or is using `typing` different from built-in module. If you know to want ramifications of python2 end of life read [Sunsetting Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). If you have legacy python2 you might try [porting to python3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)

Comment: Is there any tool that makes it easy to convert python2 code to python3

Comment: @Sam You shouldn’t need to convert a project to Python 3 just to run it. Depending on the complexity of the project that can be a multi-month endeavor.

Comment: @Sam take look at [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html)

Answer (score 0):

pip [stopped supporting Python 2 in version 21](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support). You’ll need to install an older version of pip for Python 2.