# Installing old versions of dependencies within a python virtualenv and receiving ERROR: No matching distribution found for tiledtmxloader==3.1.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pygame, tmx

I'm trying to run an [old github project](https://github.com/ksallberg/wallstreet_tycoon). It runs on `python2.7`, so I created a virtualenv for it, which uses `pip==20.3.4` and am trying to install everything and run it within `source ./venv/bin/activate`

The dependencies in it are listed as

```
      install_requires = ['Django == 1.5.1',
                          'pyglet >= 1.1.4',
                          'tiledtmxloader >= 3.0.3',
                          'pygame>=1.9.1',
                         ],
```

but since the newest versions of these packages don't won't with `python2.7` or the project the way that it is, I changed these dependencies to `==` instead of `>=`

```
      'Django == 1.5.1',
      'pyglet == 1.1.4',
      'tiledtmxloader == 3.0.3',
      'pygame==1.9.1',
```

I was able to install the older version of pyglet but for the other packages, I received errors like

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tiledtmxloader==3.1.0 (from versions: 3.1.0.131)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tiledtmxloader==3.1.0

RROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame==1.9.1 (from versions: 1.9.2b5, 1.9.2b6, 1.9.2rc1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4.dev0, 1.9.4rc1, 1.9.4, 1.9.5.dev0, 1.9.5rc1, 1.9.5rc2, 1.9.5, 1.9.6rc1, 1.9.6rc2, 1.9.6, 2.0.0.dev1, 2.0.0.dev2, 2.0.0.dev3, 2.0.0.dev4, 2.0.0.dev6, 2.0.0.dev8, 2.0.0.dev10, 2.0.0.dev12, 2.0.0.dev14, 2.0.0.dev16, 2.0.0.dev18, 2.0.0.dev20, 2.0.0.dev22, 2.0.0.dev24, 2.0.0, 2.0.1.dev1, 2.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame==1.9.1
```

Are the older versions of these packages available for download? All I want to do is execute the program, so it makes way more sense to just download the older packages and run the program as is, than to try to convert it to python3. I don't even know if I'll like the program after I update it.

---

I would like to know how to download these packages, so that I can run the project as is, without having to do any edits

Comment: "*Are the older versions of these packages available for download?*" Why not check it at the download site? Do you know where from `pip` gets its packages?

Comment: pygame 2.0.1 still supports python2, so you should use that. Especially since it looks like 1.9.1 might not have been on pip.

Comment: @phd I do not, I actually don't really understand how pip works

Comment: @phd So I downloaded [tiledtmxloader](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pytmxloader/downloads) as well as [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) from the source. I dragged them into my venv(venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages) and unzipped them there, I'm looking up stuff that says I might have to build them now, I'm not sure, the instructions are kind of confusing

Comment: @Starbuck5 I'm not going to do that, I'm trying to run this old program as is

Comment: @Sam totally fair. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `pip` downloads packages from [Python Pakckage Index](https://pypi.org/) so when you run `pip install tiledtmxloader` it goes to https://pypi.org/project/tiledtmxloader/#history (well, actually it goes to [Simple API](https://pypi.org/simple/tiledtmxloader/)) looking for a version that corresponds to your platform (processor architecture, 32- vs 64-bitness, Python version). Currently `tiledtmxloader` provides exactly one version 3.1.0.131 that only works with Python 3 so it's certainly not what you want.

There are Homepage and Download links at PyPI that lead to Google Code Archive. At the [download](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pytmxloader/downloads) page there are a few old version. I tried the latest, 3.1.0.115, it works with Python 2.7. So try this:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/pytmxloader/tiledtmxloader-3.1.0.115.zip
```

Change `setup.py`:

```
  install_requires = ['Django == 1.5.1',
                      'pyglet >= 1.1.4',
                      'tiledtmxloader @ https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/pytmxloader/tiledtmxloader-3.1.0.115.zip',
                      'pygame>=1.9.1',
                     ],
```

This is direct reference, see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, I had to change the `install_requires` into `==` instead of `>=`

```
install_requires = [
    'Django == 1.5.1',
    'pyglet == 1.1.4',
    'tiledtmxloader == 3.0.3.114',
    'pygame==1.9.3',
],
```

The pygame and tiledtmxloader couldnt download from pip, so I had to download the `pygame` and `tiledtmxloader` from source. I used `python==1.9.3` instead of `1.9.1`, there were some problems with `1.9.1`

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/pytmxloader/tiledtmxloader-3.0.3.114.zip
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/61/06/3c25051549c252cc6fde01c8aeae90b96831370884504fe428a623316def/pygame-1.9.3.tar.gz#md5=ac744ea6952b68d5f2b6d02a6d8e836c
```

---

I had to do this all within a python2 virtualenv which is talked about on this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67656933/6331353).

Other than the fact that I had to use pygame 1.9.3 instead of 1.9.1 everything worked