# How to install pip in Python 2.7 on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: python, pip, python-typing

I'm trying to install pip via

```
sudo -H python -m pip install -U pip
```

but this results in the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, _Error)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(mod_name)  # Do not catch exceptions initializing package
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named typing
```

Comment: Don’t, don’t, don’t. 1) Python 2 is end-of-life 2) Install Python from https://www.python.org/downloads/ if you _have_ to (exceedingly bad idea).

Comment: You need to downgrade pip for your Python. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758/ . Your problem is different but the process of downgrading and URLs are the same.

Answer (score 12):

According to phd's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869296/installing-pip-is-not-working-in-python-3-6/65871131#65871131)

The later versions require Python 3.6+. The syntax f"" is supported by Python 3.6+.

To install pip for Python 2.7 install it from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/ :

```
- curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
- python get-pip.py
- python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0"
```

The last command is to upgrade to the latest supported version. For Python 2.7 the latest supported is currently pip 20.3.4.

For Python 3.4 install from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.4/ . For Python 3.5 — https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/ .

For Python 3.4 the upgrade command is

```
- python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.1.2"
```

Comment: It is. Thanks. Had a read and fixed. @JohnHennig

Comment: try to install pip for python 2.7 in Mac Big Sur,  still showing error `command not found: pip` after Successfully installed pip-20.3.4

Comment: oh, have to use `python -m pip <module_name>`  to install modules

Comment: @RY_Zheng All good?

Comment: yes. it. works. thanks