# what python modules to be installed for running pip?

Tags: python, pip

I've been trying to install pip on python 2.7 and keep getting errors like unsupported hash type sha256, md5, etc from hashlib

Any modules to be installed from python to make it work ?

Comment: Recent versions of `pip` do not support Python 2 anymore. Make sure to use one from before `21.0`. Or even better: upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade your python version and you will be fine

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how many non-trivial Python projects have you migrated from 2 to 3 already?