# vitualenv does not work for my 2.7.9 python installation

Tags: python, installation, pip, virtualenv, python-2.x

After installing:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Running it yells:

```
    C:\programs\python\Python27\Scripts>virtualenv.exe
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\programs\python\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File "C:\programs\python\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File "C:\programs\python\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
      File "C:\programs\python\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
      File "C:\programs\python\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\run\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from ..app_data import make_app_data
      File "C:\programs\python\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\app_data\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
        from platformdirs import user_data_dir
    ImportError: No module named platformdirs
```

Any ideas why this is happening ?
pip 1.5.6

Comment: Do you really still have to use Python 2.7?

Comment: hopefully for a transition :)

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am asking because many packages have stopped supporting Python 2.7, so you should install virtualenv and create your virtual envs in Python 3.x instead if you can.

Comment: I mean legacy code

Comment: pip came with python 2.7.9 distribution

Comment: First, [upgrade `pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758).