# Errors given when trying to install SQLAlchemy in a vagrant VM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, vagrant, virtual-machine

Inside the vagrant box after typing, `vagrant ssh`
i tried to run the following two lines,

```
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, engine
```

which gave the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

When i try to install sqlalchemy using following code `pip install SQLAlchemy` it install the app but no change to the outcome.
when i try `pip3 install SQLAlchemy` it gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line
57
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy 1.4 requires either Python 2.7 or Python3.6+.  Your server is running Python3.5.  Try `pip install --upgrade 'sqlalchemy<1.4'`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869296/installing-pip-is-not-working-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLAlchemy 1.4 requires either Python 2.7 or Python3.6+. Your server is running Python3.5. Try `pip install --upgrade 'sqlalchemy<1.4'`

I tried as suggested in the comment section and now it's working like a charm.