# Pyinstaller AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'walk_stack'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, setuptools

When I want to install `Pyinstaller` module whit this command:

```
pip install pyinstaller==3.4
```

I got the following error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error 1

I searched and found out that I should upgrade `setuptools` module:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

but I got this error:

> AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'walk_stack'

and `pip` doesn't work no longer. What is the solution to solve this problem and successfully install Pyinstaller?

Configuration:

- OS: Windows 7
- Python: 3.4.3
- Pip: 6.0.8

Comment: The latest version of pyinstaller is 4.7. Do you absolutely need 3.4?

Comment: I think the latest version of pyinstaller supportable in python 3.4.3 is pyinstaller 3.4.

Comment: Oh I completely missed that, does your project absolutely require that you use 3.4? It's going to be fairly unsupported at this point, and you may run into more of these issues with packages in general

Comment: Well, in some reasons I have to work with Windows 7 and XP, and therefore I chose the latest version of python which is supported in both 7 and XP.

Comment: Downgrade `pip`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758