# Python pip not working as expected in 3.4

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, version, python-3.4

> C:\Python34\lib\site-packages_distutils_hack_*init*_.py", line 158, in pip_imported_during_build     cls.frame_file_is_setup(frame) for frame, line in traceback.walk_stack(None) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'walk_stack

I am getting this error in Python 3.4 when I try to use pip.

Can someone help?

I tried upgrading pip and it shows the same error.

Comment: Downgrade `pip`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758

Comment: python get-pip.py
    cls.frame_file_is_setup(frame) for frame, line in traceback.walk_stack(None)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'walk_stack'

Comment: I tried installing through get-pip.py seeing same error

Comment: Did you download `get-pip.py` for Python 3.4?

Comment: Also I think you need to remove `C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_distutils_hack`