# Can't create virtual environment with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, virtualenv

I' trying to create a virtual environment with a custom python 2.7.15 on a centOS server,I followed the steps from this website (https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215489338-Installing-and-using-virtualenv-with-Python-2),but when I use virtualenv to create a python virtual environment something happens.Here is the code.

```
$ virtualenv -p /public/home/myname/opt/python-2.7.15/bin/python venv
RuntimeError: failed to query /public/home/myname/opt/python-2.7.15/bin/python with code 1 err: '  File "/public/home/myname/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py", line 152\n    os.path.join(base_dir, exe) for exe in (f"python{major}", f"python{major}.{minor}")\n                                                           ^\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\n'
```

I've searched the net for answer but I failed to reach one,can anyone explain what happened? Is the anaconda that prevents me from creating my virtual environment?

I searched the Error but it seems no one came across with the same error I met.

Comment: Your error says you have Python 3.8 installed. Why do you need end-of-life Python 2 environment?

Comment: I have to use a software written with python2..

Comment: And you cannot use 2to3 to convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `virtualenv` installed for Python 2.7. Install/upgrade tools:

```bash
$ /public/home/myname/opt/python-2.7.15/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade "pip<21.0"
$ /public/home/myname/opt/python-2.7.15/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Now create the venv:

```bash
$ /public/home/myname/opt/python-2.7.15/bin/python -m virtualenv venv
```

Comment: pip no longer supports Python 2. Is this why you set `<21.0`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, exactly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758