# pip reporting erorr Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-QW1_6h/setuptools/

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pip, rhel7

I am unable to get python pip working by any means.

Please find below my commands and the output...

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
yum install python27-python-pip
scl enable python27 bash
which pip
pip -V
yum install python-devel
```

Output:

```
pip -V
pip 8.1.2 from /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Honestly, I don't know what the issue is. As you would observe that any command results into the same error.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting gspread (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/4f/033ebf34778745061b67b104ef212ed5b05fa65a530f345f88c4355fdcc3/gspread-5.10.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-TWIm0_/gspread/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-TWIm0_/gspread/
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

**cat requirements.txt**

```
gspread
argparse==1.4.0
google-auth==1.34.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
```

**python --version**

```
Python 2.7.18
```

**pip install --upgrade pip**

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/19/e63fb4e0d20e48bd2167bb7e857abc0e21679e24805ba921a224df8977c0/pip-23.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-6AeVvO/pip/setup.py", line 7
        def read(rel_path: str) -> str:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6AeVvO/pip/
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

Now checking pip list
**pip list**

```
pip (8.1.2)
setuptools (0.9.8)
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Upgrading pip also no charm.
**pip install --upgrade pip**

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/19/e63fb4e0d20e48bd2167bb7e857abc0e21679e24805ba921a224df8977c0/pip-23.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-M7VmLt/pip/setup.py", line 7
        def read(rel_path: str) -> str:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-M7VmLt/pip/
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

**python -m pip install -U pip**

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/19/e63fb4e0d20e48bd2167bb7e857abc0e21679e24805ba921a224df8977c0/pip-23.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-vVpaff/pip/setup.py", line 7
        def read(rel_path: str) -> str:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vVpaff/pip/
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Your `pip` and `setuptools` are way too old even for Python 2.7. First you need to upgrade them; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758