# Pip from Python 2.7.10 installed via pyenv-win cannot install any packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pyenv, pyenv-win

I installed pyenv-win to create virtual environments in windows. One of the environments I need requires Python 2.7.10. To create virtual environments for Python versions below 3.3 I need to install the package "virtualenv", since only the versions 3.3+ have the "venv" package pre-installed. The problem I encountered was when I tried to install the virtualenv package with
`pip install virtualenv` or `python -m pip install virtualenv`
I literally got nothing, no error and no installation, nothing happens.

I tried to install other packages like numpy and nothing happens as well.

When I input the command `pip install virtualenv -v` it shows the command `Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org` and then nothing happens yet again.

I tried with versions of Python3 installed via pyenv-win and, for example, with Python 3.12.0 everything worked fine.

If it helps the pip version is 7.0.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `pip` 7.0.1 is too old and unusable. First upgrade to 9.0.1 and then `pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0"` . Or install from `get-pip.py`; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758

Comment: @phd trying to install from the instructions provided from that link I get the message `DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.`
after executing the `python get-pip.py' command`

Comment: That's just a warning, ignore it.

Comment: @phd yes, I did that and ignored it, but nothing happens yet again after I execute the `python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0"` or with pip 9.0.1

Comment: `python --version`? `pip --version`? `python -m pip --version`?

Comment: @phd those work: Python 2.7.10
pip 7.0.1

Comment: It seems `pip` was not upgraded.